# pip install Pillow fails

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I can't install pillow on my computer anymore. When I tried `pip install Pillow`, I get warnings and then 2 errors :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pillow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pillow
```

I saw a lot of people in the same case and I tried all the solutions but nothing worked. Do you have any idea on how to re-install pillow?

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to diagnose a problem yet. What warnings do you see? Have you configured an alternate index than PyPI (show `pip config list`)

Comment: `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002871DF31908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pillow/`
the waring I get 4 times.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? You’ll need to get cert files or disable ssl.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following two commands

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

so as to update pip; python's package manager (you may even find that pip is already up-to-date). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTBZv.png) will be the message shown when pip is already up-to-date

After that, you may simply run this to install the latest version of the Pillow package:

```
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Answer (score -1):

Install with whatever you use to run Python, not `pip` directly. For example:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

See https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ for more details.

Comment: While this is good advice, it can not be the cause of the issue in the question because there are pillow releases which support 2.x as well.